# Getting a specific file from network activity

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am logging in and navigating a website using Selenium. At a certain point, I need to get a file, which I found by opening the inspector, switching to the network tab and reloading the page. The name of the file is a xhr file called "history". Below is a screenshot of the inspector.

[image: The inspector]

I have tried using the following code (driver is a ChromeDriver, with which I opened the web page I inspected):

```
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
System.out.println(js.executeScript("return history"));
```

However that returns

```
{back={}, forward={}, go={}, length=2, pushState={}, replaceState={}, scrollRestoration=auto, state=null}
```

It would be nice to have a solution, which works with Selenium but it of course is not necessary.

Comment: What do you mean by "Get a file"?

Comment: @Deadron Well have some method, which returns it. Or some way to store it, either in a variable or as a file.